# Buy X Get Y Free rule is not working in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have create a rule under `Shopping Cart Price Rules`.

In **Actions**

```
Apply: Buy X Get Y Free(discount amount is Y)
Discount Amount: 1
Discount Qty step(Buy X): 2
```

**And provide condition**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  5
```

`Note:` `5 is category Mobiles`

The rule is created successfully. But in home page nothing is displayed about this rule and nothing happened for this rule while shopping. That means it showing the rule is not working. How can i make it working, and what is wrong with my approach. Need your help...

```
Note: magento version is 1.7.0.2
```

Comment: your price rule itself wrong.. Then how it will work!!..

Comment: @Pavan Kumar My rule is Buy X Get Y Free(discount amount is Y). And Buy 2 get 1 free means what i am trying to do.

Comment: So the rule is, if we buy 2 qty of X product, then Y will be free.. IS this your rule??

Comment: no i mean,  buy 2(X) product and get 1(Y) product free.That is buy any 2 product from particular category get 1 product free.

Comment: so buy 2 apples and get 1 orange free from fruits category.. Is this is correct? or buy 2 apples, get 1 more apple for free?? Which one from the above?

Comment: Both can correct..Is any problem??

Comment: @Pavan Kumar , i think this will make problem for making condition. So i prefer the first that is buy 2 apples and get 1 orange free from fruits category.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49717/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-deepus)

Comment: @Pavan Kumar the image you give in the chat is can't open for me. So please post answer as text here..

Answer (score 3):

In the admin panel, click on Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules (because we are dealing with products in the cart)

In the Conditions tab,click the little plus symbol and select 'Product Attribute Combination'.

Select the new plus symbol and select category. Click on the '...' and select the category for the products you want to have in the basket for you to get the discount.

Now click on the Actions tab, in 'Apply' have 'Percent of product price discount'. In Discount Amount, enter 100 (for 100%). In the conditions at the bottom, click on the plus symbol and select Category. Click on the '...' to select the category for the products you want to apply the 100% discount to.

This will get you 100% off all products in cat b when you have >= 1 products from cat a in the cart.

**NOTE: Test this functionality as many times you can.. Test it with adding multiple quantity of main product or by adding the multiple quantity of free product.**